# remove characters from old pretty urls, httpd/htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old blog that I´ve updated recently. The old blogposts have bad (old) urls indexed by searchengines. I´m creating better ones now but getting dups in Google Webmasters due to that.

I´ve solved most of it with rewriteRule but Im stuck at special signs like question mark, exclamation and dots.

I have tried almost every snippet that is suggested in other threads here, but with no luck...

Problem is like this:

I have an old blog post with url:

```
http://example.com/blog/username/thank-god?-its-friday!!!._b-37483.html
```

After my code update on the blog the system now spits out:

```
http://example.com/blog/username/thank-god-its-friday_b-37483.html
```

Both links above works and I get duplicate content in Google for it.

How do I remove '?', '!', '.' in a proper way in httpd.conf (or htaccess)?

Below is my code in httpd.conf involving rewrites

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ä(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)å(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ö(.*)$ /$1o$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Å(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ä(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ö(.*)$ /$1o$2 [L,R=301]
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)/(.+).html$       ./blog/view/blog.php?page=$1&mode=$2 [NC]
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+).html$            ./blog/blog.php?page=$1 [NC]
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)/$                ./blog/view/blog.php?page=$1 [NC]
Rewriterule ^blog/$                     ./blog/blog.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)/(.+)$        ./blog/view/blog.php?page=$1&mode=$2 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ ./blog/blog.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+)$ ./artiklar.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this right below `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]*)[^/A-Za-z0-9_-]+([^/]*\.html)$ /$1$2$3 [L,R=301]
```

to clean out all those unwanted characters.

Comment: Hi Jon, that snippet worked! The only thing is that it removes the underscore in the end of the url. Like: ... k-god-its-friday_b-37483.html becomes: k-god-its-fridayb-37483.html Do you have a quick fix for this? Would be very greatful!

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. Had some problem when putting the snippet above the removal of åäö, but after that, like a charm! Thank you very much!